# Where do we have to write queries in Laravel: in model, controller or routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm little confused with the database queries in the laravel, where do we have to write our queries: in controllers, models or routes ?

I've been through many tutorials and I see so much difference. Just creating confusion.

Kindly explain somebody

Answer (score 15):

It depends on different factors, but in short you can write them both in Model, Controllers or Repositories

If you're writing a controller action and you need a query that you'll use only once, it's perfectly fine to **write the query directly in the controller** (or even in the route's closure ).

For example, if you want to get all users of type `admin`:

```php
$admins = User::where('type', 'admin')->get();
```

Now, suppose you need to get the admins in more than one controller method; instead of rewriting the same query, you can create a Repository class to wrap the access to the users' Model and **write the query inside the Repository**:

```php
class UserRepository
{
    public function getAllAdmins()
    {
        return User::where('type', 'admin')->get();
    }
}
```

Now in your controllers you can inject the Repository and use the same method of the Repository to get the admin users: this will keep your code DRY as you don't have to repeat the same query among the controllers' actions

**Controller**

```php
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepo)
{
     $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
} 

//controller action
public function index()
{
     $admins = $this->userRepo->getAllAdmins(); 
}
```

Finally, let's suppose you need a query to count the number of the admin users. You could write this query in the `UserRepository`:

```php
public function getAdminNum()
{
    return User::where('type', 'admin')->count();    
}
```

And it would be ok, but we can note that the `User::where('type', 'admin')` fragment of the query is shared with the query in `getAllAdmins` So we can improve this by using [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) :

**User Model**

```php
public function scopeAdmins($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', 'admin');    
}
```

by this, in the `UserRepository` methods we can rewrite our previous queries as:

```php
public function getAllAdmins()
{
    return User::admins()->get();
} 

public function getAdminNum()
{
    return User::admins()->count();  
}
```

And i've just showed you a case in which a **query would be writed inside a Model**

Comment: where can i store my repositories?. i mean in a particular location.

Comment: @JcJohn You can read this article for more information: https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce

Answer (score 0):

You do not write any query in `Model`. `Model` is just for mapping the class that you are going to use for a table like User Model will be mapped to users (plural of model name).

You do not write queries in the routes closures like this

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function(){
    $totalProblems = Problem::count();

    $solvedProblems = Problem::where('solved', 1)->get()->count();

    $unsolvedProblems = Problem::where('solved', 0)->get()->count();

    return view('Pages.index', ['totalProblems' => $totalProblems, 'solvedProblems' => $solvedProblems, 'unsolvedProblems' => $unsolvedProblems]);
}]);
```

This is considered as bad practice, its just for testing purposes.

You always write your queries in the controller method associated with your route like this

```
Route::get('test', 'HomeController@test');
```

and in your `HomeController`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Problem;

    class HomeController extends Controller {

        public function test(){
            $user = User::all();
            return view('Pages.test')->withUser($user); //or

            return view('Pages.test')->with('user' , $user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "always", there is times when you don't put the queries directly in the controller for example in the repository pattern

Comment: yeah I agree, but we avoid this since routes are not purely meant for this. @amirbar